# Partial View doesn't see that BeginForm is part of HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mef, partial-views

In my main app I would like to load a partial view from a plug-in DLL into the main view. Right now I am using `@Html.Partial(/~bin/PluginName.dll/PluginName.ViewName.vbhtml)` as my way of trying to look at the partial view. This is the error I'm getting:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
Files\root\b3a37fd6\7fe17e9b\App_Web_cucontractnumberplugin.cucontractnumbersearch.vbhtml.1
45470.d2zb2yt5.0.vb(43): error BC30456: 'BeginForm' is not a member of 
'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'.
```

I have a class that loads the dlls into the shadow directory upon app start-up. All that is in my partial view (for now) is a text box. I eventually would like to load a plugin of a search into my main view.

Here is my partial view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ChangeCUNumber", "PluginName"))

@Html.TextBox("strCUNumber")


End Using
```

**If you need anything clarified please ask! Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add `@Inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` in my plugin view